# Consul, vault and postgres containers don't communicate

Tags: docker, postgresql, docker-compose, consul, vault

I'm trying to set up Consul with Vault for secrets management for Postgres with Docker. Here is my configuration

Dokcerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

ENV VAULT_VERSION 0.11.1
ENV CONSUL_VERSION 1.2.3

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
     build-essential \
     git \
     curl \
     wget \
     vim \
     net-tools \
     iputils-ping \
     dnsutils \
     zip \
     unzip \
  && wget -O /tmp/vault.zip "https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/${VAULT_VERSION}/vault_${VAULT_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip" \
  && unzip -d /bin /tmp/vault.zip \
  && chmod 755 /bin/vault \
  && rm /tmp/vault.zip \
  && wget -O /tmp/consul.zip "https://releases.hashicorp.com/consul/${CONSUL_VERSION}/consul_${CONSUL_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip" \
  && unzip -d /bin /tmp/consul.zip \
  && chmod 755 /bin/consul \
  && rm /tmp/consul.zip \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  consul:
  container_name: consul.server
  command: agent -server -bind 0.0.0.0 -client 0.0.0.0 -bootstrap-expect=1
  image: consul:latest
  volumes:
    - ./config/consul/config:/consul/config
  ports:
    - "9300:9300"
    - "9500:9500"
    - "9600:9600/udp"
  networks:
    - consul_network

vault:
  container_name: vault.server
  image: vault
  ports:
    - "9200:8200"
  cap_add:
    - IPC_LOCK
  depends_on:
    - consul
  environment:
    - VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG={"backend":{"consul":{"address":"${LOCAL_IP}:9500","advertise_addr":"http://${LOCAL_IP}", "path":"vault/"}},"listener":{"tcp":{"address":"0.0.0.0:8200","tls_disable":1}}}
  command: server
  networks:
    - consul_network

db:
  image: postgres:10.5-alpine
  volumes:
    - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  environment:
    - CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR=${LOCAL_IP}:9500
    - VAULT_ADDR=http://${LOCAL_IP}:9200
  networks:
    - consul_network
    - database_network

networks:
  consul_network:
    driver: bridge
  database_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

And also I'm keeping LOCAL_IP in .env file:

```
LOCAL_IP=10.0.2.15
```

(I'm developing on Vagrant machine hence the address).
I was following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@pcarion/a-consul-a-vault-and-a-docker-walk-into-a-bar-d5a5bf897a87) and I assume db container should have access to both consule.server and vault.server from but it doesn't. (?)

Secondly, I've connected into vault.server and tried to get vault status which responded with

```
Error checking seal status: Get https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

I have just started learning about Docker and frankly I don't even know where to begin looking for some answers so if anyone could give me direction I'd be more than grateful.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The `VAULT_ADDR` environment variable needs to be set to `http://127.0.0.1:8200`

When normally starting the `vault` server you'd see this in the output when running with TLS disabled:

```
You may need to set the following environment variable:

    $ export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems that it's changed nothing. Should I replace all of {LOCAL_IP} with 127.0.0.1? And if so could you explain why?